# How to post follow/unfollow with instagram api

Tags: android, instagram-api, mobile-application

I want to create a mobile application. And I want to send message and post to others account. Basically I want to promotion of my company in Instagram App. Now I want to know that are these activity possible in instagram app using api key?

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't try to read official Instagram API Docs from help page?

This is from the developer help page what you're searching for:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/[user-id]/relationship?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

You must modify for you the relationship between the current user and the target user.

```
PARAMETERS:
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token.
ACTION  One of: follow/unfollow/block/unblock/approve/deny.
```

So if you're logged in, you should fetch the valid access token after that, you can choose your action follow or unfollow with user-id.

[You can read more from this page](https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/)